# Spring JPA selecting few fields from child and parent tables

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have below 2 entities.

```
@Entity
public class Subscriber()
{
    int subId;
    String subName;
    String subAddress;
}

@Entity
public class Book()
{
    int bookId;
    int hiredBy; // -> References Subscriber.subId
    String bookName;    
}
```

I have below 2 entities. When I add relationship in JPA, it fetches all the columns from parent table. Instead, I want only the subName field to be fetched when inner joined. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Show your queries, but yes. "Select b, s.subName from Book b join Subscriber s on b.hiredBy = s.subId". Having a relationship in the model helps too though as you can always make it and any other attributes you want 'lazy' - check out the many tons of JPA tutorials on the subject. Lastly, you can control what is or isn't fetched via EntityGraphs and specifying it as a LoadGraph or Fetchgraph query hint to control what is lazy and what is eager in the managed entities returned.

Answer (score 0):

JPA usually works with entities and the relationship between entities. Ideally if your entity book has a dependency on `Subscriber`, the relationship should be defined in the book entity. It is true that JPA by default, eager fetches the `Subscriber` entity but you can also lazily load the `Subscriber`.

```
@Entity
public class Book()
{
    int bookId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subId")
    Subscriber hiredBy;

    String bookName;
}
```

If additional fields are required when querying the entity `Book`, then most probably a DTO is required since we are no longer just querying the Book `entity`.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

class SubscriberBookDto {
    int bookId;
    int hiredBy;
    String hirerName;
    String bookName;

    public SubscriberBookDto(int bookId, int hiredBy, String hirerName, String bookName) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
        this.hiredBy = hiredBy;
        this.hirerName = hirerName;
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

There are multiple ways to build this DTO. One option would be to query the `Book` entity and construct the DTO from it. Querying the `Book` entity should be a good option despite it brings all the fields from `Subscriber`.

If a more refined SQL query behind the scene is desired, then it is best to query the database to bring the only the fields which are required to build the DTO. It might look something like:

```
// in Book's jpa repository
@Query("select new com.stackoverflow.SubscriberBookDto(" +
        "book.id," +
        "subscriber.subId," +
        "subscriber.subName," +
        "book.name) " +
        "from Book book " +
        "inner join book.hiredBy subscriber ")
List<SubscriberBookDto> getBookSubscribers();
```

I would say both options are good. I would prefer the first one since there is less code written and the overhead is low. I would advise to perform optimisation on JPA level when it is really needed, otherwise it is a premature optimisation.